# unavailable shared library com.android.hardware.usb

Tags: android

I am tryin to develop an apk to mount the SDcard to PC(as a part of bigger project).
But every time I run my program I get the following error:
Package com.prac requires unavailable shared library com.android.hardware.usb(or com.android.future.usb) depending on whether I am using virtual device with build target as SDK API12(or google sdk api11).

I need to run the above apk on a API10 device, so I guess using com.android.future.usb would be suitable.

Please suggest me a appropriate solution because I have already wasted 5 days trying to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need the USB compatibility library for Gingerbread, contained in the [Google APIs add-on](http://code.google.com/android/add-ons/google-apis/index.html) if you want to build against com.android.future.usb.  As noted on the USB Accessory [page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html), however, not all devices will support this; it's something that the device manufacturers need to add and at this point, I believe, only the Nexus One and Nexus S running version 2.3.4 have this support.

Comment: But I have tried with both the approaches: google add-on library and android sdk 12. but for either scenario I get same error.

Comment: Do you see this error running your program in the emulator or on an actual device?  If it's an actual device, the note on the USB Accessory page applies; unless it's a device running 2.3.4 (e.g., upgraded Nexus S or Nexus One) or Honeycomb, it doesn't have the necessary API support and there's no way to get the libraries onto the device, since they're part of the platform and not something you can ship with your application.

Comment: I am getting the error both on emulator and device(even though it's running on 2.3.4).

Comment: I was too, until I added the following line to the <application> element of the manifest - <uses-library android:name="com.android.future.usb.accessory"/> . This is described under the "Manifest and resource file examples" on the USB Accessory page mentioned in my initial answer.  After adding this line, I was able to successfully call USBManager.getInstance() both in the emulator and on my Nexus One running 2.3.4.